# Font issue in rmarkdown slides with Metropolis theme

Tags: r, r-markdown, pandoc, xelatex

I am using the `rmarkdown` package to produce PDF slides with the Metropolis theme. Recently, I noticed that the equations started to appear differently - they use a different font.

Minimal example of `*.Rmd` file:

```
---
output: 
  beamer_presentation:
    theme: "metropolis"
    latex_engine: xelatex
    keep_tex: true
---

## Problem with font
$$f(x_i\mid\mu,\sigma^2) = \exp\left\{-\frac{(x_i-\mu)^2}{2\sigma^2}\right\}$$
```

which, when knitted in RStudio, produces:
[image: slide produced with rmarkdown]

This looks different from what is obtained when compiling the same slide directly in LaTeX with xelatex:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{metropolis}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{Problem with font}

\[f(x_i\mid\mu,\sigma^2) = \exp\left\{-\frac{(x_i-\mu)^2}{2\sigma^2}\right\}\]

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

which produces:
[image: slide produced with beamer]

This does not look like a big difference, but in other equations some special characters are missing, and the font size is slightly different, affecting the whole layout of my slides.

After some investigation, it turns out that commenting out those two lines in the tex file produced by `rmarkdown` makes it better:

```
  %\usepackage{unicode-math}
  %\defaultfontfeatures{Ligatures=TeX,Scale=MatchLowercase}
```

Is the `unicode-math` package the (only) culprit here? How to solve this problem and make sure that Metropolis uses the right fonts without manually changing the tex files?

Thanks in advance for your help!

System configuration:

- RStudio 1.2.1335
- rmarkdown 1.15
- pandoc 2.3.1 (through RStudio)
- [Metropolis theme](https://github.com/matze/mtheme) 1.2
- [Fira Sans font](https://github.com/bBoxType/FiraSans) 4.3
- XeTeX 3.14159265-2.6-0.999991 (TeX Live 2019)

Comment: seems like rmarkdown sets the pandoc `mathspec` variable for some reason? Try unsetting it. I searched the default template (`pandoc -D latex`) for `unicode-math` and that came up... see https://pandoc.org/MANUAL.html#templates

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. Forcing pandoc to use the mathspec package solved the problem, as @tarleb suggested below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you are seeing is, indeed, the effect of the *unicode-math* package. There is a simple way to work around this by forcing pandoc to use the *mathspec* package instead. This can be done by setting `mathspec: true` in your metadata

```
---
mathspec: true
output: …
---
```

or by setting the respective variable when calling pandoc

```
---
output: 
  beamer_presentation:
    theme: "metropolis"
    latex_engine: xelatex
    pandoc_args: ["--variable=mathspec"]
---
```

There is only a minor, very subtle, and mostly inconsequential difference between the two. I'd suggest to use the first version, as it is simpler.

See TeX StackExchange for a discussion of the [differences between unicode-math and mathspec](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/118244/148113).

Comment: This solves my problem, thank you so much! (I was not aware of this difference between unicode-math and mathspec.)